# Extracting key value from object into array of objects with specific fields

Tags: javascript, coding-style, lodash

So I have this data:

```
fields = ['a', 'b', 'c']
data = [{r: 1, a: 2, b: 3, c: 4, h: 5}, {r: 4, a: 9, b: 1, c: 4, h: 5} ... ]
```

and I want to be able (preferred with lodash) to be able to get to this:

```
newData = [{r:1, h:5, values: [{name: 'a', value: 2},{name: 'b', value: 3}, {name: 'c', value: 4}], .....]
```

Meaning only the fields from the 'fields' object be taken out of each object in array (they always exist) and put into 'values' property that has an array of them in the format displayed here.

Would love to hear suggestions of the cleanest way to achieve this!

I did this :

```
function something(data, fields) {

  const formattedData = _.map(data, (currData) => {

    const otherFields = _.omit(currData, fields)

    return { 
      ...otherFields, 
      values: _.flow( 
        currData => _.pick(currData, fields), 
        pickedFields => _.toPairs(pickedFields), 
        pairs => _.map(pairs, pair => { 
          return { name: pair[0], value: pair[1] } 
        })
      )(currData)
    }
  })

  return formattedData
}
```

which works, but I'm wondering if it isn't a bit complicated.

Comment: would love to see what you have tried to achieve this!

Comment: I edited to add what I did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_.flow()` method creates a function, which you can extract and name. In addition, the 1st function in the flow, accepts more than 1 parameter, so you don't need to pass it explicitly. Since `_.toPairs()` is unary, you don't need to wrap it in an arrow function.
The object creation is a bit annoying. I've used `_.zipObject()`, but it's still cumbersome.

Now you can use the function create by `_.flow()` in your main function, and it's pretty readable:

```js
const { flow, pick, toPairs, map, partial, zipObject, omit } = _

const propsToObjs = flow(
  pick,
  toPairs,
  pairs => map(pairs, partial(zipObject, ['name', 'value'])),
)

const fn = (data, fields) =>
  map(data, currData => ({
    ...omit(currData, fields), 
    values: propsToObjs(currData, fields)
  }))
  
const fields = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const data = [{r: 1, a: 2, b: 3, c: 4, h: 5}, {r: 4, a: 9, b: 1, c: 4, h: 5}]

const result = fn(data, fields)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Using lodash/fp, we can make the flow function even nicer, since lodash/fp functions are auto-curried and iteratee-first data-last (not the reversed order of parameters):

```js
const { flow, pick, toPairs, map, partial, zipObject, omit } = _

const propsToObjs = flow(
  pick,
  toPairs,
  map(zipObject(['name', 'value']))
)

const fn = fields => map(currData => ({
  ...omit(fields, currData), 
  values: propsToObjs(fields, currData)
}))
  
const fields = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const data = [{r: 1, a: 2, b: 3, c: 4, h: 5}, {r: 4, a: 9, b: 1, c: 4, h: 5}]

const result = fn(fields)(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) through the objects in data and then check if the key is in the fields array:

```js
fields = ["a", "b", "c"];
data = [
  { r: 1, a: 2, b: 3, c: 4, h: 5 },
  { r: 4, a: 9, b: 1, c: 4, h: 5 },
];

let newData = data.map((o) => {
  let newObject = {};
  newObject.values = [];
  for (let k in o) {
    if (fields.includes(k)) {
      newObject.values.push({
        name: k,
        value: o[k]
      });
    } else {
      newObject[k] = o[k];
    }
  }
  return newObject;
});

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: This is good and probably a bit more readable but I wanted something with lodash. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

You could destructure the object, pick the wanted properties and return the rest of the object with wanted values.

```js
const
    fields = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    data = [{ r: 1, a: 2, b: 3, c: 4, h: 5 }, { r: 4, a: 9, b: 1, c: 4, h: 5 }],
    result = data.map(o => {
        const values = fields.map(name => {
            let value;
            ({ [name]: value, ...o } = o);
            return { name, value };
        });
        return { ...o, values };
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```